# can we bind (click) event while creating the html element in angular 8?

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I am trying to create HTML input boxes on click of a plus button with below code
HTML:

```
<button type='button' value='Add Button' class="btn btn-primary add-multiple-text-btn" id='addButton' (click)="addMultipleInput()"><i class="icon icon-plus"></i></button>
```

ts:

```
addMultipleInput(){
      if(this.counter>7){
        $(".add-error-msg").show().delay( 10000 ).hide(0);
        return false;
      }
      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + this.counter).attr("class","d-flex TextBoxDiv form-group");
      newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label class="mr-3 pt-1" for="textbox'+this.counter+' ">'+ this.counter + ' </label>' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control validate width80" style="width:80%" name="textbox' + this.counter +
            '" id="textbox' + this.counter + '" value="" >'+
            '<span class="delete-inputs"><i class="icomoon icon-trash2 text-danger d-inline-block pt-2 pl-2" **(click) = "deleteInput()"** title="Delete" id="deleteInput'+this.counter+'"></i></span>');
      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");

      this.counter++;
    }

deleteInput() {
      alert("clicked");
    }
```

can we bind the (click)="deleteInput()" while creating the input field? And how we will create the deleteInput() function definition in same file?
Help will be appreciated.The code is mixed with angular and jquery.I am new to angular

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list for your functions. When someone click add or delete button you can remove or add data in your list and when you are update your table, you can see your 
alterations. If u want to change button and attributes, you should change your button with a script code.

Comment: if i add the event like (click)="deleteInput()" while creatig the input field dynamic,it is not calling the function deleteInput() which is written below to it.